# Correct ashift value for zpool

Tags: zfs

I am new to zfs and setting up a KVM server. I am learning that setting the correct ashift for the zpool is very important. I created a zpool with 4 1.92TB Kingston DC600M drives without setting ashift. After creating, I'm not sure what this value is set to. This is the drive layout with a sector size of 512:

```
root@kvm1:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.75 TiB, 1920383410176 bytes, 3750748848 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SEDC600
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 54FF5EA0-CE6E-3145-89A3-234A10DC8AA4

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3750731775 3750729728  1.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  3750731776 3750748159      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1
```

This is the zpool created:

```
root@kvm1:~# zpool status
  pool: vm_images
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        vm_images                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50026b7686b6cde8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50026b7686b6cbfb  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50026b7686b6ce16  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50026b7686b6ce02  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Now, if I use zdb, it appears to show the correct ahsift of 9 for each mirror:

```
root@kvm1:~# zdb -C
vm_images:
    version: 5000
    name: 'vm_images'
    state: 0
    txg: 32042
    pool_guid: 18113470955376656359
    errata: 0
    hostid: 940822259
    hostname: 'kvm1'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 2
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 18113470955376656359
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'mirror'
            id: 0
            guid: 17129579534474406438
            metaslab_array: 267
            metaslab_shift: 34
            ashift: 9
            asize: 1920368902144
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 129
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 12141588404671866473
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50026b7686b6cde8-part1'
                devid: 'scsi-350026b7686b6cde8-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:1b:00.0-scsi-0:0:13:0'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 130
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 4374722492424561155
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50026b7686b6cbfb-part1'
                devid: 'scsi-350026b7686b6cbfb-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:1b:00.0-scsi-0:0:14:0'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
        children[1]:
            type: 'mirror'
            id: 1
            guid: 4063060495541825533
            metaslab_array: 256
            metaslab_shift: 34
            ashift: 9
            asize: 1920368902144
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 132
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 2117188888921191837
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50026b7686b6ce16-part1'
                devid: 'scsi-350026b7686b6ce16-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:1b:00.0-scsi-0:0:17:0'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 133
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 14967214633990567153
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50026b7686b6ce02-part1'
                devid: 'scsi-350026b7686b6ce02-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:1b:00.0-scsi-0:0:18:0'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 134
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

However, the zpool ashift appears as zero?

```
root@kvm1:~# zpool get ashift vm_images
NAME       PROPERTY  VALUE   SOURCE
vm_images  ashift    0       default
```

I am in test mode now and looking for advice on how I should possibly wipe and setup the zpool with the ashift set to 9?